# Пополнение списка в асинхронном коде

Tags: python, aiohttp

Я написал асинхронный парсинг сайта, при обработке ответа от сервера, я нужные данные записываю в список, но как быть, если я использую aiohttp?

Как заполнять данные в асинхронном коде?

Comment: Точно так же, метод `append` у списков работает одинаково везде. Непонятно, в чём у вас проблема

Comment: Ну вот отправил я запрос через aiohttp, далее вызываю новую функцию, передавая туда ответ от сервера, как быть тогда?

Comment: Просто берёте и передаёте. В чём проблема-то?

Comment: Вы не понимаете, если у меня цикл и вызов функции идет 20 раз, то список будет просто перезаписываться, а не пополняться

Comment: `append` по природе своей в принципе никак не способен перезаписывать список, хоть вы его миллион раз в цикле запускайте. Да, я не понимаю, потому что вы не можете внятно объяснить свою проблему ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Из- за того, что у меня много ссылок и запросов я использую aiohttp,чтобы все запросы отправить быстро-асинхронно, и если я передам в функцию ответ сервера, то он мне запишет в массив 1 значение, а не будет каждый раз заполнять его

Comment: Сейчас покажу примером

Comment: В массиве будет ровно столько значений, сколько раз вы вызовите `append`, и всё будет нормально заполняться, даже быстро-асинхронно. Ваша проблема по-прежнему непонятна

Comment: Вот смотрите, я изначально создаю пустой список, а далее его заполняю через append, пустой список я создаю в новой функции, в которую передаю ответ сервера, получается каждый раз мой список будет хранить 1 элемент, как быть мне в этом случае?

Comment: Очевидно, создавайте список за пределами функции

Comment: Похоже я понял Вас, спасибо